# Is Wi-Fi harmful to one's health?

Tags: health-outcomes, bioelectromagnetics

Is Wi-Fi harmful to one's health, so much so that we should live without it? There are different sides to this debate - why should I believe one side more than the other? Indeed, we live with Wi-Fi every day and this is acceptable according to regulations, so it must be fine for our health to be exposed to it. But I know somebody who lives without Wi-Fi because she thinks that it serves as a potential threat to her health, and she claims that she is more sensitive to it than other people. Is this possible?

Comment: It's nigh impossible to live without wifi - everywhere you walk you're likely to be walking through a wifi network's range.

Comment: What debate? Where does this debate exist? Wifi is just another radio signal, no different from the _many_ others that have been passing through our bodies since the day we were born.

Comment: @CareyGregory the "debate" is between people who believe in the scientific method vs. nutcases that think naturopathy blogs always tell the gospel truth, because their aunt's sister-in-law's nephew once heard this thing on the radio.

Comment: I have heard anecdotal reports that it gives people slight headaches and makes it hard for them to sleep (comments here: http://www.globalhealingcenter.com/natural-health/10-shocking-facts-health-dangers-wifi/ ). No idea about long term stuff. GL!

Comment: I think currently this question is too broad. One can't prove that there is no negative health effect whatsoever because there are billions of possible negative health effects. Right now, the answer would be [that the WHO concludes that there's no negative effect discovered until today, but they haven't searched through all possible effects...](http://www.who.int/peh-emf/research/en/). The question would be a lot better if a list (or one) supposed effect was given (brain cancer or something like that) and one could talk about that.

Comment: It depends on whether the owner/operator of the WiFi has "deep pockets" and is worth suing.

Comment: Related: [How strong are Wi-Fi signals?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/482014/205125)